# Makefile targets as cross product of two lists

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I spent the better part of the day trying to figure this out. I want to use make for building a golang project with different os targets and multiple binaries. I think I want to use gnu make

My stripped down Makefile looks like:

```
main= mailworker websocket worker init
os= linux freebsd darwin

all: $(main)

$(main): ensure_build_path
    @echo "Build $@ Version: $(GIT_REV)"
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_PREFIX)/$@
    GO111MODULE=on GOARCH=amd64 $(GO) build  -o $(BUILD_PREFIX)/$@ ./bin/$@/$@.go
```

Now I want to add `GOOS=$(os)` to the build command / generate a target for every main X os combination. My test / lern Makefile looks like:

```
os=linux freebsd darwin
main=mailworker websocket worker init

define build_template =
t:=$(addprefix $(1), $(2))
$(info $(t))
$(t):
    @echo $(1) $(2) $$@
endef

$(foreach P, $(main), $(foreach O, $(os), $(eval $$(call build_template, $O, $P))) )
```

There are at least a dozen variants of this I tried. I think my main problem is how to declare `t` inside the template. I tried many "concat" methods I found regarding make. Also `:=` or `=` for t. I think `:=` is the right one. But I am not sure about anything anymore ;)

To be clear, I want make to "generate" targets that look like:

```
mailworker_linux:
    GO111MODULE=on GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GO) build mailworker

mailworker_darwin:
    GO111MODULE=on GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 $(GO) build mailworker
```

Is this a good way doing this? And if so, where is my misunderstanding.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems here.  First, your invocation of `call` is incorrect: you're escaping it which means it won't be expanded before it's given to eval; that's not correct it must be expanded first.  You want:

```
..., $(eval $(call build_template,$P,$O))..
```

(only one `$` before `call`.

Second, the rule for a variable you define that is used with an eval/call pair is that every macro expansion inside that variable that you want to be seen by the eval has to be escaped.  In your case you did escape the `$@` as `$$@` which is good, but the other thing you need to escape is uses of `$(t)`, because that variable is not set until the `eval` sets it.  So you need to write your variable like this:

```
define build_template =
t := $(addprefix $(1)_,$(2))
$$(info $$(t))
$$(t):
        @echo $(1) $(2) $$@
endef
```

(I added in the missing `_` to your `addprefix`).  It doesn't matter whether you use `=` or `:=` here; they both work the same since you're always using this variable in an immediate-expansion context.

As an aside, it seems everyone runs straight to eval and call which are extremely powerful but also difficult to use and understand.  An alternative that uses more straightforward make constructs might be something like this:

```
getmain = $(word 1,$(subst _, ,$@))
getos = $(word 2,$(subst _, ,$@))

TARGETS := $(foreach P,$(main),$(addprefix $P_,$(os)))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): %:
        @echo $(getmain) $(getos) $@
```

Comment: thanks @madscientist how do I set per rule variables with this? This does not work
$(TARGETS): %: env=key
$(TARGETS): %:

Comment: It's hard to understand in unformatted comments.  You might want to ask a new question.  But if I understand what you're asking, you can just use `$(TARGETS) : env = var`.  Static patterns are actually explicit rules, not implicit rules, even though they have "pattern" in the name.

Comment: the last rule can't have variable assignments in it. make throws an error about that

Comment: You can't make variable assignments and rule definitions the same line.  A single line can only be one or the other not both at the same time.  You have to use two different lines: one for the variable assignment and the other for the rule definition.